# Keycloak - Assign a client scope to user with a specific role

Tags: oauth, keycloak

given the following setup:

- A user with a realm role "foo-admin"
- A client named "foo" (Direct Access Grants Enabled, public)
- A client scope "some:scope" (Optional Client Scope of client "foo")

When requesting an access token with the client "foo" the user should get the scope "some:scope" based on his realm role "foo-admin". Users without that role should not be able to get that scope (even when requesting it).

I followed this [blog post](https://robferguson.org/blog/2019/12/30/angular-oauth2-keycloak/) and assigned the "foo-admin" admin role under the scope tab of the client scope. As far as i can tell this setup does exactly what we want, but to be honest i find the tooltip in the scope tab confusing, because we did not create a user role mapping or something in the first place. Tooltip: "Scope mappings allow you to restrict which user role mappings are included within the access token requested by the client."

Is this setup ok? How and why does assigning the role in the scope tab work, when the tooltip says something about restricting mappings?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User's access token only includes realm roles not it's scope.

If you want to user's mapping scope, have to call extra REST API calls.

#### Overview

[image]

#### Setups

1. Run Keycloak v18.0.2
2. Create `development` realm
3. Create `foo` client
4. Create `foo-admin` role
5. Create `some:scope` client scope
6. Assign `foo-admin` into `some:scope`
   [image]
7. Assign `some:scope` Optional Client Scope into `foo` client
   [image]
8. Create `user` user
9. Assign `foo-admin` role into `user`

[image: List item]

Now ready to demo.

Demo by curl command
It will shows, user's access token includes assigned realm role.

Get Master Token - credential is admin/admin and one hour - for testing
[image]

#### Demo

1. Get Mater & User `access -token`

```
MASTER_TOKEN=$(curl --location --request POST "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token" \
-s \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'password=admin' | jq -r '.access_token')
echo $MASTER_TOKEN


ACCESS_TOKEN=$(curl --location --request POST "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/development/protocol/openid-connect/token" \
-s \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=foo' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=user' \
--data-urlencode 'password=1234' | jq -r '.access_token')
echo $ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Result
[image]

[image]

2. Display User `access -token` 's role

```
jwtd() {
    if [[ -x $(command -v jq) ]]; then
         jq -R 'split(".") | .[0],.[1] | @base64d | fromjson' <<< "${1}"
         echo "Signature: $(echo "${1}" | awk -F'.' '{print $3}')"
    fi
}

jwtd $ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Result
[image]

You can verify user token by [JWT.io](https://jwt.io/) web site.

[image]

1. Get User's role's scope

3.1 Get User's Role (*Overview red circle 3) - `foo-admin`

Find `user` 's `user id` -
`jq` is useful `-r` option remove "double quate"
'.[0]`is get first item of array.` .id` get only id field.

```
USER_ID=$(curl -s --location 'http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/development/users/?username=user' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer '"$MASTER_TOKEN" | jq -r '.[0]'.id)
echo $USER_ID
```

[image]

```
curl -s --location 'http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/development/users/'"$USER_ID"'/role-mappings' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer '"$MASTER_TOKEN" | jq
```

[image]

3.2 Get client `foo` 's scopes `some:scope` (*Overview red circle 1)

Get Client ID

```
CLIENT_ID=$(curl -s --location 'http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/development/clients/?clientId=foo' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer '"$MASTER_TOKEN" | jq -r '.[0]'.id)
echo $CLIENT_ID
```

[image]

Get Client `foo` 's optional scope list

```
curl -s --location 'http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/development/clients/'"$CLIENT_ID"'/optional-client-scopes' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer '"$MASTER_TOKEN" | jq
```

[image]

3.3 Get  scope `some:scope` 's assigned role  (*Overview red circle 2)  - `foo-admin`

Get `some:scope` scope 's id
filter by `jq` matched `some:scope` name from scope's list array.

```
SCOPE_ID=$(curl -s --location 'http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/development/client-scopes' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer '"$MASTER_TOKEN" | jq -r -c '.[] | select(.name | contains("some:scope")).id')
echo $SCOPE_ID
```

[image]

From `scope id` get it's assigned role. it will be `foo-admin"` role.

```
curl -s --location 'http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/development/client-scopes/'$SCOPE_ID'/scope-mappings/realm' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer '"$MASTER_TOKEN"  | jq
```

[image]

#### Final conclusion

The `user` assigned `foo-admin` role.
And it's role assigned `some:scope` scope.
So user can do under by `some:scope` scope.